# How to address military person as a civilian in business relationship

Tags: professionalism, title

How to properly address a person in a military hospital who is commander/chief/head-of-institution, university professor and colonel at the same time?

I am a civilian from a software development company, offering a service.
Should I address him professor, colonel or commander/chief...

solution: it was professor

thanks for your advices

Comment: What country, what army, what title, what relationship, what position, what question, ... ?

Comment: Have you asked him?  He's the best person to tell you how he prefers to be addressed.

Comment: @JaneS no, this would be my first contact with him and I would like to be prepared

Comment: Start with "sir", then ask him how you should address him.  That is the most professional way to approach this.  I say this as a civilian who has worked with both military personnel and academics.  He may well tell you to address him by his first name.  Ask.

Comment: Just a reminder to our commentators of our [Be Nice](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: Is your service related to the professor role or his military role?

Comment: You have your solution, but it is never inappropriate to address a military person by their rank.  It's a title they've sought and earned.  If they'd rather you use something else, they will tell you, but will not be offended.

Comment: @WesleyLong: After thirteen-plus years in the military, I agree that the use of the title is acceptable.  But it is not always sought and not always earned.  Those who least deserve it, however, are the ones most likely to appreciate your using it.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't go wrong with sir, at least the first time, then whatever reply you get I'd use the title on his email signature if you're contacting by email. If not by email then:-

I would use his military title if he is a soldier for general communication.

If I'm specifically contacting him just because he is a professor I would use professor.

If I had a bit of time and cared enough, I'd ring his secretary and ask.

Comment: One visual cue is if he is wearing his uniform.

Comment: Sir is always a valid way to address a military officer.

Comment: Sir is always a way to address a male officer, @Chad. Most female officers I know would be insulted.

Comment: @HLGEM - Only if they are Air Force...

Comment: The OP does mention it's a man, but in general I agree, nurses are officers and you don't call them sir. It depends on the army, in some there is no gender for 'sir' so the equivalent applies equally.

Answer (score 4):

A few suggestions.
1) Google him, if he his high profile enough there may be some clues online.
2) Call the hospital contact number (if you have it) and ask them.
3) If you've had any correspondence via email see how he identifies himself in his email signature.
4) If they have a contact directory see how he is listed.
5) Follow what Jane S says and start with Sir.

I don't think there is a definite answer to this question.